# Distributional Laplacian of logarithmic potential

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Let $f(z) = \int_\mathbb{C} \log |w - z| \,d\mu(w)$ for some measure $\mu$.  How does one show that $\mu = \Delta f / 2\pi$ in the sense of distributions?

As a related question, how can one show that the distributional Laplacian $\Delta f$ of $$f(z) = \int_0^{2\pi} \log|e^{i\theta} - z|\,d\theta$$ is simply Lebesgue measure restricted to the unit circle?

Comment: Answered at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2258115/161311

Comment: To be honest, I haven't answered this for general $\mu$, and in fact I'm not totally sure it's correct in this generality (though it might).